# How do I fill missing values in a column with already existing values in the same column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe containing 3 columns of interest (30 columns in total).
One for location, the second for name and the last for description, such as:

```
import pandas as pd

inp = [
    {"Location": "Boston", "Name": "Apple", "Description": "Green"},
    {"Location": "Paris", "Name": "Orange", "Description": ""},
    {"Location": "Paris", "Name": "Apple", "Description": ""},
    {"Location": "Austin", "Name": "orange", "Description": ""},
    {"Location": "Berlin", "Name": "Apple", "Description": ""},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Location    Name Description
0   Boston   Apple       Green
1    Paris  Orange       
2    Paris   Apple            
3   Austin  orange            
4   Berlin  Apple
```

I have about 10 000 columns like this and I want to fill missing values in "Description" based on "Name"="Boston (not taking "Location" into account) but not fill the rows where Location is "Berlin".

Ideal Output:

```
Location    Name Description
0   Boston   Apple       Green
1    Paris  Orange     
2    Paris   Apple       Green   
3   Austin  orange   
4   Berlin  Apple
```

Ignoring Berlin is as simple as:

```
df.loc[df["Location"] != "Berlin"]
```

Output:

```
    Location    Name    Description
0   Boston  Apple   Green
1   Paris   Orange 
2   Paris   Apple   
3   Austin  orange
```

But I can't figure out how to fill the missing descriptions. Keep in mind that there are alot of different names and descriptions (about 1000 of each).

I know I could extract "Boston" values and then merge on "Name", but I feel there should (and probably is) a simpler way.

Comment: Wait. Why did row 4 (idx 3) become 'Austin Apple' in the output?

Comment: my mistake, this is now corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) first and assign back filtering out Berlin via [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc):

```
df.loc[
    df['Location'].ne('Berlin'),
    'Description'
] = df.groupby('Name')['Description'].transform('first')
```

`df`:

```
  Location    Name Description
0   Boston   Apple       Green
1    Paris  Orange            
2    Paris   Apple       Green
3   Austin  orange            
4   Berlin   Apple
```